# Have a private swap file per process

Tags: linux, swap, virtual-memory

Is there a way to assign a swap space or swap file JUST to one process or a group of processes while other processes still use normal swap mechanism?

Here is some context. I have a process that uses huge amount of memory (larger than physical memory) and I want to direct the swapped pages owned ONLY by this process to a swap file that I create on SSD.

I am using Linux. I am open to use containers if that helps with the solution.

Comment: Containers use the system memory (incl. swap space managed by the system) so they won't help you here.

Comment: The only way to isolate swap per program that I know of, is putting the program in a VM.

Comment: Maybe you'll find a solution by looking into `mmap`. You could probably allocate memory from a mmapped file located on the SSD instead of anonymous pages (the default used by `malloc()`). The system should only write pages to the file if memory gets low. But I'm a noob and don't know for sure.

Comment: What would be the downside to potentially having other processes swapping to the same location (SSD/etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Since 3.14 (circa mid 2014) linux kernel supports [per-cgroup swap files](https://lwn.net/Articles/592923/).

This support is made available via the `CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP` kernel config knob. (Depends on `CONFIG_MEMCG`)

The path to the *private* swapfile is to be set by writing to the `memory.swapfile` controller.

Comment: It has never been merged: https://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1404.0/02530.html