# How to create a private swap file for a specific process or cgroup in Linux?

Tags: swap, virtual-memory, cgroups

I'm currently attempting to generate a swap file in Linux that is exclusive to a particular process or cgroup. After going through the LWN article which discusses the patches that enable this functionality (https://lwn.net/Articles/592923/), I'm unable to find any resources or references on how to execute it.

Despite having CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP set, I'm still unable to locate the memory.swapfile controller, even after reading the answers in this Unix Stack Exchange question ([Have a private swap file per process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356202/have-a-private-swap-file-per-process)). Can anyone provide some guidance or tips on how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance for any help you may offer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that using cgroups using the mainline kernel. The patch that you linked has never been merged.

You could create a VM with QEMU and use a memory-backed-file instead: https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/devices/ivshmem.html.